# Should "zoom" tag also apply to the videoconferencing software?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently "zoom" tag description is

> Questions related to desktop zooming effect

Now, during Covid-19 lockdown many people are using the tag for Zoom videoconferencing program. Should we create a new tag for videoconferencing app or modify "zoom" tag's description to include it?

Comment: I'd rather propose a new tag [tag:zoom-app].

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had a look upon questions tagged with [zoom](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/zoom). Only a small portion of them are related to the meeting app "zoom". I was able to only spot three. Most are using it to show that the question is related to desktop zooming effect.

So I guess creating a new tag should be the correct decision here. Something like [zoom-app](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/zoom-app) as suggested or [zoom-meeting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/zoom-meeting) or even [zoom-meeting-app](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/zoom-meeting-app).

So we won't end up in the hassle of refining all these question tagged with [zoom](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/zoom) which are actually related to "desktop zooming effect".

---

**Edit**:

[zoom-meeting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/zoom-meeting) Has been created. I was able to find and edit [14 related questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/zoom-meeting) adding the new tag. We can also create some synonyms like [zoom-meeting-app](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/zoom-meeting-app) or [zoommtg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/zoommtg) as suggested in comments.

Comment: [tag:zoom-meeting-app] sounds better IMO.

Comment: Yeah, definitely a separate tag for those would be good. Out of the three, I like [tag:zoom-meeting] most. The `-app` part seems redundant and adds little info.

Comment: `zoom-app` is definitely not a good choice.  It presumes that the Zoom Video Communications company will never produce any other kinds of app.