# Replace 'zoom' tag with 'magnification' (synonymise + merge)?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Six months ago, SurvivalMachine asked [Should “zoom” tag also apply to the videoconferencing software?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19194/677341) At the time, it seemed that relatively few questions about the Zoom meeting app used the [zoom](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/zoom) tag. Today, however, it seems that a larger share of questions tagged [zoom](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/zoom) are about the Zoom meeting app; if fact, some use both [zoom](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/zoom) and  [zoom-meeting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/zoom-meeting) [1].

For this reason, I would like to reduce the risk of incorrectly tagged Zoom app questions by doing the following:

1. Create the tag [magnification](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/magnification),
2. Synonymise [zoom](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/zoom) (source) with [magnification](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/magnification) (target),
3. Merge the tags,
4. Clean up the questions about the Zoom meeting app that are tagged [magnification](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/magnification).

As a result, the number of future questions about the Zoom meeting app that are tagged [zoom](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/zoom) should significantly decrease.

[1] Since zooming or magnification is an important accessibility features, these two categories of software should obviously be kept clearly separated.

---

**Update 13.01.2021**: muru's suggestion turned out to be better than mine. See Zanna's comment:

> The [zoom](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/zoom) tag has been renamed to [zooming](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/zooming) and I think all the questions about Zoom have been removed from it. Thanks to muru for the idea and to everyone who helped with editing work. Also thanks Tsundoku for the question!

Comment: of 120 questions in the zoom tag, I counted 22 about the zoom application

Comment: The [zoom] tag has been renamed to [zooming] and I think all the questions about Zoom have been removed from it. Thanks to muru for the idea and to everyone who helped with editing work. Also thanks Tsundoku for the question!

Comment: @Zanna I have updated my question with text stating what was implemented, so if you like, you can tag it with [meta-tag:status-completed].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alternate suggestion: use [zooming](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/zooming) for zooming in and out and continue using [zoom-meeting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/zoom-meeting) for the meeting app. Nuke the [zoom](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/zoom) tag, don't keep it, don't synonymise it and don't allow it to be created again.

Comment: +1 much better idea

Comment: What happens when we stop allowing a tag to get created again, how does it look for the user? Unsure how to search for banned tags myself to try it out. I'm asking this because if the user can still see a description for a banned tag, we should still change its excerpt and explain to the user that they need to use one of these 2 new tags.

Comment: @Dan https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wAd8.png I don't know if additional information can be provided, but I don't think that's needed.

Comment: @Zanna it's been a few days, with no opposition to this, so shall we move ahead with [tag:zooming]?

Comment: Thanks for the nudge! :) I have renamed the tag, just need to remove the questions about Zoom software from it. Will probably finish that up tomorrow

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is a good idea, because the feature of being able to zoom is usually called *zoom* and not *magnification*. I think that dedicating the [zoom](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/zoom) tag to the zoom application would not solve the problem of the tag being used inconsistently - it would continue to be used for both zooming in and out, and the particular software application.

I think the only thing we can do here is to make the usage guidance of the zoom tag say something like:

> THIS TAG IS FOR QUESTIONS ABOUT ZOOMING IN AND OUT, NOT FOR THE ZOOM APP (use the zoom-meeting tag instead).

Comment: "it would continue to be used for both zooming in and out, and the particular software application" How about splitting up the [tag:zoom] into something like [tag:built-in-zoom] (or [tag:desktop-zoom]) and [tag:magnifier]? That would also reduce the risk of incorrect tagging. I'm not entirely convinced that adding guidance to the tag wiki excerpt will be sufficient.

Comment: @Tsundoku I am quite confident that adding usage guidance will not be sufficient - I just think it's the lesser evil. There are more kinds of zooming like in applications so I wouldn't favour breaking up the tag. I think the action of zooming should take precedence over the zoom software, which might go away or get renamed in the future anyway.

Answer (score 0):

From a user experience, it would be very bad to do the magnification idea or even remove zoom. And this is getting too complicated just because of the zoom app. I would suggest, to simplify this to:

1. Keep `zoom` as is. This is used if you see the questions at hand for zooming in general. (Zoom in, zoom out). Very few will be actually typing zooming for this or even worse, magnification. Imagine applying the whole -ing to other tags. It would be a mess.
2. Keep `zoom-meeting` for the zoom app and explain it in the description.

The actual tag of zoom would always be zoom tag. The use of the zoom meeting would be the zoom-meeting tag. This way it is simple.